# Exclusive Where Clause

Tags: t-sql, where-clause

I am trying to get a result where only cars that have:
Wing, Door and Windscreen are selected.

And Only Cars that have ONLY those three parts.

I can not seem to get the where clause correct, here is what I have:

## Table

```
CREATE TABLE Cars (
NameID int Identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
CarMake varchar(20) NOT NULL,
CarPart varchar(10) NOT NULL)
```

## Data

```
INSERT INTO Cars (CarMake, CarPart)
VALUES  
('FIAT' ,'Wing'),
('FIAT' ,'Door'),
('FIAT' ,'windscreen'),
('FORD' ,'Wing'),
('FORD' ,'Door'),
('FORD' ,'windscreen'),
('FORD' ,'Seat'),
('FORD' ,'Bumper'),
('MINI' ,'Windscreen'),
('MINI' ,'door'),
('RENUALT'  ,'Door'),
('RENUALT'  ,'Seat'),
('RENUALT'  ,'Wing'),
('VOLVO'    ,'wing'),
('VOLVO'    ,'door'),
('VOLVO'    ,'bonnet'),
('VOLVO'    ,'windscreen'),
('VOLVO'    ,'bumper'),
('VOLVO'    ,'seat')
```

## Statement

```
SELECT CarMake
FROM Car_CTE
WHERE CarPart = 'Wing' AND CarPart = 'Door' AND CarPart =  'Windscreen'
GROUP BY CarMake;
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select only those groups having only those 3 carparts

```
SELECT CarMake
FROM Car_CTE
GROUP BY CarMake
HAVING sum(case when CarPart IN ('Wing', 'Door', 'windscreen') then 1 else 0 end) = 3
AND sum(case when CarPart NOT IN ('Wing', 'Door', 'windscreen') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

And to get the ones not having these parts do

```
SELECT CarMake
FROM Car_CTE 
GROUP BY CarMake
HAVING sum(case when CarPart IN ('Wing', 'Door', 'Windscreen') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/108461/3)

Comment: Thank you Juergen, but a little unsure how I would adapt this answer for my other queries, as I have other results I have to generate like only cars with those specific parts and no others, and those cars with out any of those parts

Comment: I added a second query

Comment: That is a very clever way of generating the answer, Bravo, never seen a case statement put inside a sum before, it is using the case as a type of Boolean isn't it ?

Comment: The case returns `1`  every time carpart has one of these 3 values. The  `sum` adds up these `1`s. The result must be `0` meaning the case was never true.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, but does that mean the case will auto return 0 if its not true? as there is no else to state its return ?that is what I meant as a type of Boolean?

Comment: It returns `null` for the else part. You could change the case to `case when CarPart IN ('Wing', 'Door', 'Windscreen') then 1 else 0 end` to make it more clearly what was intended. Then it will return `0` for the else part.

Comment: Jurgen, None of them seem to bring back the correct answer the first brings back two rows when should only bring back one and second brings back no rows at all.

Comment: Of course. I corrected that. I added a SQLFiddle.  And in the Fiddle I added `BMW` as a car that does not have any of the described values. Your example data did not contain such a car.

Comment: The only funny part is that I needed the `else` part in the `case` to make it work. I am investigating this on occasion.

Comment: Since your `CarPart` column is of type `varchar` that would mean a mix of types for the `else` part - an `int` as in `1` and a `varachar`. That does not work and returns `null` for the `sum`. Just in case you wanted to know.

Comment: Thank you the and answer and the explanation are superb.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to create another table with list of all cars and then use the table formed by parts so you don't use DISTINCT clause

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.CarMake
FROM Cars c
WHERE EXISTS(
   SELECT 'Wing'
   FROM Cars c2
   where c.carMake = c2.carMake
   AND c2.carPart = 'Wing'
)
AND EXISTS(
   SELECT 'Door'
   FROM Cars c2
   where c.carMake = c2.carMake
   AND c2.carPart = 'Door'
)
AND EXISTS(
   SELECT 'Windscreen'
   FROM Cars c2
   where c.carMake = c2.carMake
   AND c2.carPart = 'WindScreen'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, was just wondering if this would be better as a CTE ?

Comment: You can use Car_CTE too. I use Cars because your posted table was Cars ;)